# Is this a right calculation of Homology groups?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $X$ be a circle $S^{1}$ and f a map $f:S^{1} \rightarrow S^{1} $;
$f(z)=z^5$.
I'd like to calculate homology groups of mapping torus of this space.$$$$
$[X \times I]/\cong$ can be depicted as a square, where veritical edges are equated in a usual way (just like when one is depicting an ordinary torus as a CW complex with one 2-dimensional cell), whilst horizontal edges are equated in a way that lower edge is going five times around the upper one ( corresponding to $z \rightarrow z^5$).
$$$$Let $B$ be an open smaller square inside the sguare corresponding to $[X \times I]/\cong$.And let $A$ an open set such that $$Y=[X \times I]/\cong=A \cup B$$
and $$A \cap B $$ deformation retracts onto  circle.
Then non-trivial part of Meyer - Vietoris sequence is:
$$0 \rightarrow H_2(Y) \rightarrow \phi: H_1(A \cap B) \rightarrow H_1(A) \rightarrow H_1(Y) \rightarrow 0 $$
$$ H_1(A \cap B) \cong Z $$
$$ H_1(A ) \cong Z \times Z $$
If $a,b$ are two circles in wedge sum of two spheres, which is homotopy equivalent to $A$, then from Hurewicz theorem embedding $$i:A \cap B \rightarrow A$$ sends generator of $$\pi_1(A \cap B)$$ to loop corresponding to loop $ab^5a^{-1}b^{-1} $ in the wedge sum. Then I deduce the map $\phi$ sends $(1)$ to $(0,4) \in Z \times Z $
Which gives me that $H_2(Y)=0$ and $H_1(Y) = Z \times Z_4 $.
Is this a proper solution?Seems a little bit strange.Thank you for all your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As OP correctly remarked in the comments, my answer was wrong! And his proof was right (I guess).**

Well done, there's just a trivial mistake you've made: $H_2(Y)=0$ would imply that the map $H_2(Y)\to H_1(A\cap B)$ is the zero map. On the other hand, the image of this map is the kernel of the map $\phi$, which you correctly described; the kernel of this map is $\mathbb Z$. Then the map $H_2(Y)\to H_1(A\cap B)$ is not the zero map (it has image $\mathbb Z$). We also know it's injective, so that $H_2(Y)=\mathbb Z$.

I think the rest is correct!

Comment: I don't really see how can $ \phi$  have non-trivial kernel since it sends the generator of $Z$ to a non-trivial element. Am I wrong?

Comment: no, in fact $\phi$ has non-trivial kernel $\mathbb Z$, and this must coincide with the image of the map coming from left!
(I tried writing it down a bit more clearly)

Comment: Could show me the kernel explicitly?I still don't see it.

Comment: uhm wait. you're right. eh eh

Comment: yup, sorry. The kernel is trivial, and therefore the second homology group is zero - my bad. I fully understand if you don't trust my judgement, though. eh. I will edit my answer accordingly